# Lucene tfidf does not have square of idf?

Tags: lucene, tf-idf

In Lucene8.2.0 source code [TFIDFSimilarity.TFIDFScorer#score(float freq, long norm)](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.java),
I cannot find squre of idf, but according to the documentation [Lucene Practical Scoring Function](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html), 
there should involve squre of idf when calculate score.

This mismatching really confuses me a lot, does the documentation not match the source code or I've just misunderstood the source code? Could someone explain it please?  Thanks in advance